# OpenCVで丸い緑の画像の位置を検出したい

Tags: python, opencv

現在、OpenCVでとあるゲームのスクリーンショットを元に解析をしているのですが、あるマークがうまく検出できずに困っています。使用しているOpenCVは3.4.2で、Python3でスクリプトを書いています。

この問題は対象の画像に依存する部分が大きいため、実際に解析している画像を貼らせていただきます。

[image: cards.jpg]
この画像を解析しているですが、カード一枚毎が大まかにどの座標に描画されているか知りたいです。
そのため、カードの切れ目に特徴点な点としてカード左上部の緑の丸の部分に注目しました。
この緑丸の座標がわかれば、緑丸毎の間隔でカード一枚毎の座標がわかるからです。

そこで以下のような緑丸だけの画像を用意しました。
[image: 緑丸]
そしてこれを元に、テンプレートマッチングや特徴点抽出を行いましたが、うまくいきませんでした。
そこで円を検出するアプローチに変更し、HoughCirclesを使い引数などを色々と変更しましたが、うまく緑丸の部分を検出できませんでした。

どのようにすれば、緑丸を認識することができるでしょうか？またはカード毎の座標がわかるでしょうか？
ご回答いただけると助かります。

Comment: 可能であれば「うまくいかないプログラム」を質問文に含めてもらった方が回答も付きやすいと思います（質問は後からでも [編集] できます）。

Comment: すみません、確かにそうでした。今回はご回答をいただいたので載せませんが、今後は載せたいと思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

手元のpython3.6環境で緑丸の外周の深緑を抽出(※1)してHoughCirclesを使ったところ、円の座標を抽出(※2)できました。

緑丸の画像は数値の有無でマッチングが難しいので、1..5の数値が入った緑丸の画像を用意する方法が最も確実だと思いますが、下記のような対応も検討してみてはいかがでしょうか。

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread(r'[フルパス]\wqraN.jpg')
# HSVに変換
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
# 緑のHSV範囲(閾値を変えたい場合は下記の範囲を変更すること)
lower = np.array([0x29,0xa3,0x70])
upper = np.array([0x49,0xff,0xa0])
# 緑以外にマスク
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
res = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask= mask)
# グレースケール化して判定
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(res, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# 円の精度を高めたい場合はparam2の値を大きくする
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(cimg, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,2,20,
                            param1=50,param2=100,minRadius=20,maxRadius=0)
circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
#描画
for i in circles[0,:]:
    cv2.circle(res,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,0,255),2)
    print("x={},y={}".format(i[0], i[1]))
# 表示
cv2.imshow('HoughCircles',res)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

※1 緑丸の外周の深緑を抽出
[image: 緑丸の外周の深緑を抽出]
※2 円の座標を抽出
[image: 円の座標を抽出]

Comment: ご返答ありがとうございます。こちらでも再現できました。お陰様で解決できました。ただ一点、後学のため追加で質問させていただきたいのですがnp.arrayで指定している値はどのようにして取ったものなのでしょうか？もしよろしければ、教えていただけると助かります。

Comment: np.arrayのHLV値は[色見本のサイト](https://www.color-sample.com/saturation/90/)から大体の値を推測して設定しました。Windows標準のペイントを使えばツールバーのスポイトアイコンから色を調べられますので、正確な値を取りたい場合はグラフィック系のツールを使うべきでしょう。RGB値を入力してHSVに変換する[Webアプリ](https://syncer.jp/color-converter)も様々なものがあります。

Comment: ご返答ありがとうございます。詳細なご回答ありがとうございました。